# Image uploading from Django-template to model is not working

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates, django-uploads

I am trying to upload profile image of user from userprofile.html template but it is not uploading to that model on admin panel. I already configured the static and media settings correctly. I am able to upload from admin panel.But uploading from template isn't working please help..

```
#forms.py
class ImageUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = accountUser
       fields = ['profile_photo',]

#views.py
def upload_pic(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
      form = ImageUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
      if form.is_valid(): 
         form.save() 
         return redirect('success') 
      else:
         form = ImageUploadForm()

  return HttpResponseForbidden('allowed only via POST')

  #user.html
  <form method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        {% csrf_token %} 
        <p>
           <input id="id_image" type="file" class="" name="image">
        </p>
        <button type="submit">Choose Picture</button> 
  </form>
```

Comment: Try use `<input id="id_profile_photo" type="file" class="" name="profile_photo">`

Comment: No, still not working

Comment: Can you show me your models? And what did you get when uploading from template? Any error log?